# Arguments object reporting incorrectly Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, console.log

Had a bit of a strange problem recently. Built a function that has a variable number of arguments, so iterates through the `arguments` object. However, currently for a sample of 4 arguments, two have merged theirselves and the space where one should have been is displaying `undefined`.

Here's the code:

```
function doSomething() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}

var week = 'One';

doSomething('Week', '==' + week, 'Number', '==8');
```

The console output of this should be:

```
>> Week
>> ==One
>> Number
>> ==8
```

However, instead I am getting:

```
>> Week
>> ==One,Number
>> undefined
>> ==8
```

Never encountered this before, and can't find anything similar to this via my own research so has anyone got any ideas as to why this is occurring?

Comment: Your code runs as expected for me.  I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/37foodkL/), check the code for weird symbols.

Comment: @raina77ow What would you class as a weird symbol?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I don't know how to reproduce this. Even swapping comma for [full width comma](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0c/browsertest.htm) just triggers the "illegal token" on output. But the code that is equivalent to what's seen there behaves correctly all the time.

Comment: This did occur in Google Apps Script, I might add but I hadn't thought to mention it as it didn't strike me as relevant due to where the problem seems to occur.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I was passing the `week` variable as an array without realising. The lack of realization occurred because the Google Apps Script `Logger` doesn't log Arrays consistently.